# How to show Merge Controls in jDiff (jEdit)?

Tags: jedit

I have installed JDiffPlugin in jEdit.

I can see a diff of two files.

However one thing is missing: I do not see Merge Controls toolbar for jDiff.

How to enable Merge Controls toolbar, so that I could able to see and use them?